# Tkinter: Give focus to filedialog.askopenfile when using overrideredirect(True)

Tags: python, tkinter

The following code display a window without the default title bar. This window contains a button that asks the user to select a file. Unfortunatly, when the button is clicked the popup asking the user to select a file appears behind the main window. How can I ensure that the popup appears on top of the window?

**Note:** if the line `window.overrideredirect(True)` is commented, the popup appears on top of the window, but the default title bar is back.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd


def open_file():
    model_file = fd.askopenfile(title="Select model", filetypes=(
        ('model files', '*.pt'),
        ('All files', '*.*')
    ))
    print(model_file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry("+100+100")
    window.overrideredirect(True) # When commented the code works properly.

    button = tk.Button(
        window, text='Select a file', command=open_file
    )
    button.grid(row=0, column=0)

    # Provide a way to easily exit.
    button2 = tk.Button(
        window, text='Exit', command=window.quit
    )
    button2.grid(row=1, column=0)

    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: FWIW, the `askopenfile` popup is **not** behind the main window on my Windows system (and it has the focus).

Comment: Oh, does it means that it is a linux related issue? (I am on Ubuntu)

Comment: Perhaps call `.withdraw()` and `.deiconify()` on your main window around the call to the file dialog?

Comment: Could be an OS issue, because how `overrideredirect` works internally would be very OS-dependent. It could also have something to do with how `askopenfile` is implemented — because I would expect focus being shifted to its dialog the normal behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper, your solution works. However, this is not optimal in terms of user experience.

Comment: @martineau it seems to be an OS related issue. I have tried to create a second window in the open_file function, i.e. `window2 = tk.Tk()`. Then, no function seems to be able to pull this second window on top of the first one. I tried `window2.lift()`, `window2.focus_force()` and `window2.attributes("-topmost", True)`.

Comment: @Theophile: Can't say I'm surprised creating another instance of `Tk` didn't work — it usually doesn't (see [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged))